# Comparing 2 lists in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 lists which I need to compare. I need to find if at least one element from List A is found in List B. I know IN doesn't work with 2 lists. What are my other options?

Basically something like this :

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ('A','B','C') IN ('A','Z','H') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END "FOUND"
FROM DUAL
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: The one in the left is not a list, but a "tuple".

Comment: There are no "lists" in Oracle. Where do you have the strings 'A', 'B', 'C' - in a PL/SQL collection (varray, nested table, etc.)? In a standard relational table? Or in some other database object that actually does exist in Oracle? As I said, "list" is not a type of object in Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this. The WITH clause is there just to simulate your "lists" (whatever you mean by that); they are not really part of the solution. The query you need is just the last three lines (plus the semicolon at the end).

```
with
  first_list (str) as (
    select 'A' from dual union all 
    select 'B' from dual union all 
    select 'C' from dual
  ),
  second_list(str) as (
    select 'A' from dual union all 
    select 'Z' from dual union all 
    select 'H' from dual
  )
select case when exists (select * from first_list f join second_list s 
                                       on f.str = s.str) then 1 else 0 end as found
from   dual
;

     FOUND
----------
         1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you can do:

```
select
  count(*) as total_matches
from table(sys.ODCIVarchar2List('A', 'B', 'C')) x, 
     table(sys.ODCIVarchar2List('A', 'Z', 'H')) y
where x.column_value = y.column_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat the conditions:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN 'A' IN ('A', 'Z', 'H') OR
                  'B' IN ('A', 'Z', 'H') OR
                  'C' IN ('A', 'Z', 'H')
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as "FOUND"
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with collection of String you can try Multiset Operators.

```
create type coll_of_varchar2 is table of varchar2(4000);
```

and:

```
-- check if exits
select * from  dual where cardinality (coll_of_varchar2('A','B','C') multiset intersect coll_of_varchar2('A','Z','H')) > 0;
-- list of maching elments
select * from table(coll_of_varchar2('A','B','C') multiset intersect coll_of_varchar2('A','Z','H'));
```

Additionally:

```
-- union of elemtns
select * from table(coll_of_varchar2('A','B','C') multiset union distinct coll_of_varchar2('A','Z','H'));
select * from table(coll_of_varchar2('A','B','C') multiset union all coll_of_varchar2('A','Z','H'));

-- eelemnt from col1 not in col2
select * from table(coll_of_varchar2('A','A','B','C') multiset except all coll_of_varchar2('A','Z','H'));
select * from table(coll_of_varchar2('A','A','B','C') multiset except distinct coll_of_varchar2('A','Z','H'));

-- check if col1 is subset col2
select * from dual where coll_of_varchar2('B','A') submultiset coll_of_varchar2('A','Z','H','B');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do something very similar but the first list is another field on the same query created with listagg and containing integer numbers like:

```
LISTAGG(my_first_list,', ') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            my_id
    ) my_first_list
```

and return this with all the other fields that I am already returning

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN my_first_list IN ('1,2,3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END "FOUND"
FROM DUAL
```